# Ember router transitions to route that doesn't exist

Tags: ember.js

I am having an issues with my ember app that whenever the login page loads in just once I can log in just fine and it takes me to the correct page. However, when I refresh the login page and then log in, it takes me to a strange route that is not set up in my router.

The correct transition should be `login` -> `authenticated.individual.info`

But the route it takes me to is `login` -> `login.individual.info`

I'm really confused as to what would cause the router to send me to a route that doesn't exist, or maybe I'm just not very familiar with how routers work.

**app/router.js**

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('authenticated', { path: '/:slug' }, function() {
    this.resource('individual',  { path: 'individual/:id' }, function() {
      this.route('info');
    });
  });
  this.route('login', { path: 'login/:slug' });
});
```

The `slug` is essentially a personal shortname connected to each user's data of their member's information.

**app/login/route.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
var bind = Ember.run.bind;

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return {'slug': params.slug};
  },

  actions: {
    login: function(credentials) {
      this.get('session').login(credentials)
        .then(bind(this, 'authenticationDidSucceed'),
              bind(this, 'authenticationDidFail'));
    }
  },

  authenticationDidSucceed: function() {
    var transition = this.get('controller.attemptedTransition');
    var individual_id = this.get('session').individual_id;
    if (transition) {
      transition.retry();
    } else {
      this.transitionTo('individual.info', individual_id);
    }
  },

  authenticationDidFail: function(response) {
    var message = response.responseJSON.error;
    this.set('controller.error', message);
  },

  resetController: function(controller) {
    controller.setProperties({error: null, notice: null});
  }
});
```

**app/login/template.hbs**

```
...
<div class='form-group'>
  <button {{action 'login' model}} type='submit' class="btn btn-default form-control">Sign in</button>
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `authenticationDidSucceed` method you need to transition to the specific route name `this.transitionTo('authenticated.individual.info')`. Instead of transitioning to a different route leaf, it looks like Ember is just looking in the current leaf for that route.

Comment: I tried that and it gave this error: `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The route authenticated.individual.info was not found`

Comment: Hmm try changing the individual route to a route instead of a resource? The resource clearing the namespace might be causing some weirdness.

Comment: I think I figured out what it was. I think I was confusing the router since the authenticated route needed a slug as a parameter and the individual route needed an individual_id as a parameter. I just changed the transition to `this.transitionTo('authenticated', this.currentModel.slug);` And then I handled the transition to the individual route after it reached the authenticated route

Comment: Awesome, glad you were able to figure it out!